# update database when a file is downloaded [PHP]

Tags: php, mysql, download, youtube-dl

```
<form method="post" action="download.php?id=<?php echo uniqid(); ?>">
<input type="url" name="vidurl">
<button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

On the other page i download the file using this code under folder "downloads"

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];      
$url = $_POST['vidurl'];
$cmd = 'youtube-dl -o /downloads/%(title)s.%(ext)s '. escapeshellarg($url);
$exec = shell_exec($cmd);
?>
```

Now the problem is how to assign the downloaded file an id (getting from the previous page) and update the file address in database for giving it to user?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will work for you.

```
<?php
//first solution

$id = $_GET['id'];      
$url = $_POST['vidurl'];
$cmd = 'youtube-dl -o /downloads/'.$id.'_%(id)s.%(ext)s '. escapeshellarg($url);
$output = shell_exec($cmd);

//second solution

//print_r($output); will give you the following output

foreach($output as $key => $value) {
    if(strpos($value, 'destination') === false) {
        // download failed or some error message
    } else {
        $destination = explode(':', $value)[1]; //full path with file id and extension
        //rename your file here here
        //$rename = rename($destination, $newdesitination);
        //insert in database
    }
}
?>
```

> ```
> output: array (
>   0 => '[youtube] Setting language',
>   1 => '[youtube] XCj-wJB5j4c: Downloading video webpage',
>   2 => '[youtube] XCj-wJB5j4c: Downloading video info webpage',
>   3 => '[youtube] XCj-wJB5j4c: Extracting video information',
>   4 => '[download] Destination: /downloads/YourID_XCj-wJB5j4c.flv',
> [download] 100.0% of 10.48M at   185.11k/s ETA 12:00',
> )
> ```